# Android Intent - How can i open file

Tags: android, android-intent

To open image or sound we can use this code:

```cs
public String getExt(String filename)
{
    int dotIndex = 0;
    for(int i = filename.length()-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if(filename.charAt(i) == '.')
        {
            dotIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    return filename.substring(dotIndex + 1, filename.length());
}

public String getTypeAction(String s)
{
    int slashIndex = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        if(s.charAt(i) == '/')
        {
            slashIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return s.substring(0, slashIndex);
}
//////
//////

MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
String ext = getExt(file_to_action.getName());
ext = ext.toLowerCase();

String type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file_to_action), getTypeAction(type) + "/*" );
startActivity(intent); !>
```

But the problem is when i want to open any different file for example: .mhtml, .bak. apk. When i do this my application is crash. I don't know where is the problem, i have application for .mhtml, .odt extenio but my application can't use this applications to open the file. 
How i can open all file format or how i can check avaliable application for any file format ?

Answer (score 1):

you can also  do  this

```
 File file = new File(filepath);

  String extension =   file.getName().substring(file.getName().lastIndexOf(".")+1);

    MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
    String type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
    Intent intent = new Intent();

    intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
  intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), type);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

This crashes because there is no application to handle that type of data, installed on your phone.

You should use [`queryIntentActivies(intent,flags)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) from the `PackageManager` to see if there is any application that can handle your `Intent`. If the `List<ResolveInfo>` size is greater than 0, than there is some application that can handle your data. If the size is 0, you should display a `Toast` and inform the user that the data can not be handled, and also do not call `startActivity()` in this case.

Comment: This is this what i looked. But i have last question why i can't open files .mthml .odt i have applications for this files, but i can't run it when i use this code.